# Prevent passing values to function/constructors in a wrong order in C++

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning C++ and my first language in JavaScript. A common pattern to prevent bugs when passing lots of parameters to a function is to pass an object instead. The benefit of it that order doesn't matter and values are always read as intended.

Example:

```
function checkStuff({param1, param3, param2}) {}

checkStuff({param2, param3, param1})
```

I find myself constantly mixing order of parameters when passing them to class constructors. Of course, compiler and IDE will scream when types are not matching - the problem starts when my constructor definition looks like this:

```
 Sprite(const std::string &textureFile, int animationSpeed, int frameWidth,
     int frameHeight, int width, int height, int scale)
```

Is there a pattern or another option I can pass to cmake on top of this `add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)` to prevent mixing these up?

Comment: You should follow sequence when we call the function; IDE provide the list of parameter sequence. I think you should follow that. There is no special way for it.
One more lengthy way is to create the typedef for each parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More structure is one way to tackle the problem and one friendly with the language. You could combine things like animation speed, frame width, frame height, etc, into a single structure. Maybe ideally the language would be less awkward about this but I do find it useful in, general, to not be tempted to have like 12+ parameters we want to pass into a single function.

Also in my opinion, `struct` is fine... or `class` with all public fields (just stylistic in C++) when all you are using the object for is transmitting multiple parameter fields. Sometimes I encounter an allergy to this in C++ (like people wanting to turn private implementation tree nodes into fancy classes with separate public/private members, when they could just be a basic C-style struct) and I don't think there should be if you're just transmitting data in C++.

You know, public vs. private. The whole point of distinguishing "public" is to protect a good chunk of your code from unpredictable use cases, to maintain invariants. You defend your "kingdom". You don't have to turn everything into a "kingdom" (don't need to arm peasants in plate mail armor). Just use C-like structs to help implement "private' implementation details if you need to do so. Use the strong "shield/pavise" of the C++ knight for the most public, widely-accessible things you design. Just like with your own private parts. I mean I don't want to stand in a train with my crotch exposed, but I need to take a shower every now and then which will require me to be naked.

Comment: haha, your answer is awesome. :D Yes, it crossed my mind to use struct - I posted this question because on multiple courses I watched it was never used - instead they were sometimes passing more than 6 parameters to a constructor. Nice to know that structs are a valid pattern to use.

Comment: None of this is to undermine the importance of maintaining invariants, to say, "This can never happen with this design", in teams especially. When you work with other people you gotta guarantee that certain things can't happen. But there's a lot of room to play around with your privates, just like in real life when we lock ourselves in our room. Don't have to design everything with public/private distinction. Get the private things done, boom, skeet-skeet, move on. Same in code.

Comment: Then again if while initializing the structure, user mixed the parameter it will be again the problem

Comment: @Mannoj That's a language/compiler design issue IMO. If common users are passing/initializing parameters in the wrong order and getting bugs as a result, they would benefit from a more forgiving language that compiles faster. I don't mean to sound elitist since I realize anyone, at any level, is susceptible to such mistakes. But there's a good reason from a compiler design standpoint why C and C++ compilers have order-dependent argument->parameter mapping. We compensate for that in my opinion stylistically when build time and/or computational efficiency isn't a concern.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use [strong-types-for-strong-interfaces](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/) approach to prevent wrong ordering and also state the intention more clearly. It could be found a bit verbose but it makes the code more readable and less error-prone when used appropriately. You can read the article for further and detailed explanation.

I am just sharing a simple demonstration how to represent the order and meaning of the constructor parameters explicitly for the `Sprite` class.

```
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename param>
class strong_type
{
public:
     explicit strong_type ( T const& value ) : m_value ( value ) {}
     explicit strong_type ( T&& value = T{} ) : m_value ( std::move ( value ) ) {}
     T& get()
     {
          return m_value;
     }
     T const& get() const
     {
          return m_value;
     }
private:
     T m_value;
};

using animation_speed = strong_type<int , struct AnimationSpeedTag>;
using frame_width = strong_type<int , struct FrameWidthTag>;
using frame_height = strong_type<int , struct FrameHeightTag>;
using width = strong_type<int , struct WidthTag>;
using height = strong_type<int , struct HeightTag>;
using scale = strong_type<int , struct ScaleTag>;

class Sprite
{
    public:

    Sprite( const std::string &texture_file , animation_speed s , frame_width fw ,
        frame_height fh , width w , height h , scale sc ) 
        :   m_texture_file { texture_file }
        ,   m_animation_speed { s.get() }
        ,   m_frame_width { fw.get() }
        ,   m_frame_height { fh.get() }
        ,   m_width { w.get() }
        ,   m_height { h.get() }
        ,   m_scale { sc.get() }
        {   }

    private:

        // There is no harm to hold the values as primitive types
        // Just take it as `strong type`
        std::string m_texture_file;
        int m_animation_speed {};
        int m_frame_width {};
        int m_frame_height {};
        int m_width {};
        int m_height {};
        int m_scale {};
};

int main() {

    // instead of
    // Sprite my_sprite { "sprites/char.dds" , 12 , 640 , 480 , 320 , 240 , 1 };

    Sprite my_sprite { "sprites/char.dds" , animation_speed { 12 } , 
                    frame_width { 640 } , frame_height { 480 } ,
                    width { 320 } , height { 240 } , scale { 1 } };
}
```

[run online](https://godbolt.org/z/KiyVQM)

Another way is passing a struct which holds the required parameters, but I don't suggest that way. Because actually it is not solving the problem, just moving it one step further. The parameters in struct still might have been left unassigned.

A demonstration :

```
#include <string>

struct sprite_parameters
{
    std::string texture_file;
    int animation_speed {};
    int frame_width {};
    int frame_height {};
    int width {};
    int height {};
    int scale {};
};

class Sprite
{
    public:

    Sprite( const sprite_parameters& params ) 
        :   m_texture_file { params.texture_file }
        ,   m_animation_speed { params.animation_speed }
        ,   m_frame_width { params.frame_width }
        ,   m_frame_height { params.frame_height }
        ,   m_width { params.width }
        ,   m_height { params.height }
        ,   m_scale { params.scale }
        {   }

    private:

        std::string m_texture_file;
        int m_animation_speed {};
        int m_frame_width {};
        int m_frame_height {};
        int m_width {};
        int m_height {};
        int m_scale {};
};

int main() {

    // instead of
    // Sprite my_sprite { "sprites/char.dds" , 12 , 640 , 480 , 320 , 240 , 1 };
    sprite_parameters params;
    params.texture_file = "sprites/char.dds";
    params.animation_speed = 150;
    params.frame_width = 320;
    params.frame_height = 240;
    params.width = 640;
    params.height = 480;
    // params.scale = 1; OK, I forgot this, what will happen now. 
    // It is just ugly obscure bug.
    Sprite my_sprite { params };
}
```

[run online](https://godbolt.org/z/SvXMMR)

Comment: New person to C++ will feel this hard to understand. I also mentioned in a comment about `typedef` or `using`

Comment: @Mannoj Right, but the answer will persist, he/she could revisit here after a while, or this answer might be beneficial for the others who have faced this issue. It is just contributing :)

Comment: You probably want different tags for each type, since as it is they're still interchangable without error. You may also be interested in the library by the author of that blog post, https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType

Comment: @N.Shead missed that, correcting my examples, thanks